# not able to exclude firestore from firebase emulators:start

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I want to exclude local firestore and connect the prod firestore when using the `firebase emulators:start` command.
Basically, I want to run emulator for functions and hosting only so when I try `firebase emulators:start --only functions,hosting`

I get the below error:

```
i  emulators: Starting emulators:
!  Not starting the functions hosting emulator, make sure you have run firebase init.
+  All emulators started, it is now safe to connect.
```

and then it exits the shell.

there's a workaround to run two emulators `firebase emulators:start --only functions` and `firebase emulators:start --only hosting`  but why it's not working in one?

---

P.S: I want to use `emulator` method instead of `firebase serve` for debugging purpose.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the issue is with the powershell itself. The comma is a special symbol in powershell to denote an array separator. Solution is to add quotes around the parameters.

```
# This WILL NOT work
firebase emulators:start --only functions,hosting

# This will work
firebase emulators:start --only "functions,hosting"
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a bug, please [file an issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues) on the GitHub repo.