# Firebase Emulators not working in a Python Project

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying out firebase functions with Python by following this:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?gen=2nd#python-preview_2

I did

```
firebase init
```

which gave me options to initialize the emulators, functions, select project, etc.

in the directory i have the code for the functions, i have all these files - firebase.json, firstore.rules, firestore.indexes.json

This is the firebase.json file

```
{
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "venv",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true
  }
}
```

Now if i run this command: `firebase emulators:start`, I get this error:

`` "Error: Could not spawn `java -version`. Please make sure Java is installed and on your system PATH." ``

I installed JDK 20 and added it to the path variable like this:

[image]

[image]

Now when i try to run the emulator start command, i get the same error:

[image]

But if i run this command: `firebase emulators:start --only functions`, it works. The functions emulator starts up:

[image]

And i am able to hit the http end point to trigger the function invocation.

But if i run this: `firebase emulators:start --only functions,firestore`, i get this error:

[image]

No idea whats going on and how to get this to work. I have been trying to find solutions for several hours now. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message

```
"Error: Could not spawn `java -version`. Please make sure Java is installed and on your system PATH."
```

Indicates that you missed installing the java. Sometimes you may have installed java although you may get this error. To make sure java is installed in your system you may run `java –version` where you'll get a version number instead of an error. The firebase CLI checks the java version before continuing, you may check with this [Link](https://cs.opensource.google/firebase-sdk/firebase-tools/+/master:src/emulator/commandUtils.ts;drc=0ed8abf0d31efb100a16443f5cbd8328f932801c;l=478).

Also make sure that the Java executable is successfully added to the PATH environment variable on your system. It can be done by following the below steps suggested in [Documentation](https://www.qualitestgroup.com/insights/technical-hub/how-to-add-java-to-your-system-path/):

```
Right-click My Computer, then click Properties, then Advanced System Settings, then Environment Variables. Go to the Path system variable entry, and press Edit. You may see a rather long list here. At the very end, add the following:

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin
```

And when running the `firebase emulators:start --only functions,firestore` you are getting the error message that seems like an issue with the powershell itself which is suggested in this [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60011085/18265702).

> The comma is a special symbol in powershell to denote an array separator. Solution is to add quotes around the parameters. Like  `firebase emulators:start --only “functions,firestore”`

Also make sure you are using the latest version of Firebase CLI. If not, update it to the latest version by using the command `npm install -g firebase-tools`.

Also you need to consider that the python is in preview for firebase functions hence there might be chances that issue may happen and no documentation is available. Feel free to contact [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support).

Comment: restarted pycharm and it works now